# how to use replace() method for a string just one time instead of mutliple times?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, str-replace, regexp-replace

`str` is an html string (or string that contains the full html) but with some unwanted codes in between that I tried to get rid off.

This is what worked for me so far:

```
const contentClean = str.replace(/=0A/gm,"").replace(/(=09)/gm,"").replace(/(=\r\n)/gm,"").replace(/(3D)/gm,"");
```

How do I write the replace() method just one time instead of 4 times in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just alternate between each possibility with `|`:

```
const contentClean = str.replace(/=0A|=09|=\r\n|3D/gm, "");
```

Note that there's no need for capturing groups.